# IQueryable where clause checking dynamic array

Tags: c#, iqueryable

I need to know what I need to place for a where clause to filter for a dynamic list of integers.

I've been trying to search for this using `IQueryable` and 'where in array', but I do not know the terms I need to search it any better. I've been very bad and looking over code made by another person and copying patterns instead of learning what's going on.. And I just can't figure this out.

In the line of my csharp code I'm working on, I am trying to mimic the filter as from an SQL query where it would look like the following, (to grab the data from the table *jobs* with id =1, id=2, and id=3).

```
SELECT * FROM jobs j WHERE j.id in (1,2,3)
```

Where the table *jobs* might look like:

```
CREATE TABLE jobs
{   id       [int] identity(1,1) not null,
    username [varchar](50) not null,
    category [varchar](50) not null,
    ...
}
```

What I have so far:

```
string csv_ids = "1,2,3";


IQueryable<MyClass> info = null;
info = from j in db.jobs

       // this is the line I'm having trouble with
       where j.id in csv_ids.Split(',') 

       select new MyClass
       {
           // getting data
       };
```

**Solution:**
With Roy's help, I managed to head in the right direction, by adding

```
int[] ids = csv_ids.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray(); //since id is integer
```

and, mainly

```
...
// here
where ids.Contains(j.id) 
...
```

Comment: What type is Job.Id?  What is the structure of db.jobs?

Comment: j.id is an integer.  db.jobs is a table of data pulled from an SQL database. the id is the primary key.

Comment: Can you add the relevant information to your question so that the issue is easily reproducible please?  See creating a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use contains for check from list of elements

```
string csv_ids = "1,2,3";
string[] ids = csv_ids.Split(',');

var info = from j in db.jobs
       where ids.Contains(j.id)
       select new MyClass
       {};
```